# Hiding the fullscreen control of an HTML5 video on ipad

Tags: css, ipad, shadow-dom

i am pretty sure i already know the answer to this but thought i would ask it anyway. Is there a way to hide the full screen control using css: [image: full screen control] on an HTML5 video on ipad?

Just wondered if there was some kind of clever shadow DOM trickery i can use.

Thanks

Comment: You can’t tell Safari (or other browsers) how to render its standard video controls. However, you can tell it not to render its standard video controls (at least according to the HTML5 spec) by omitting the controls attribute from the video tag. So you'll have to go the long way and 'write' your custom player, or use something like: http://www.videojs.com/

Comment: Yeah, i figured that this would be the case but it doesn't hurt to ask sometimes.